# Android WebView: Handle arrow keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, dom-events

I have a simple WebView application which I want to control with the keyboard.
Is it possible to catch arrow keys in Javascript?

I have tried the following code without any luck:

```
function handleArrowKeys(evt) {
    console.info('key');                                                                                         
}

document.onkeyup = handleArrowKeys;
document.onkedown = handleArrowKeys;
document.onkepress = handleArrowKeys;
```

Javascript is enabled in the webview

```
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Have you tried `document.body.onkeydown` etc?

Comment: Yes and I do get key events from normal keys but no events from the arrow keys. The WebView does not trigger those.

Comment: I have found `shouldOverrideKeyEvent` the `WebViewClient`. I think this is going to the right direction

Comment: OK, cool.  onkeypress will never trigger for arrow keys, incidentally.  You have to use down/up for special keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should overwrite the `onKeyDown` method of WebView.
See: http://blog.csdn.net/focusxi/article/details/6780965

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    int valKey = 0;
    System.out.println("Web KEY:"); 
    System.out.println(keyCode);    

    switch(keyCode){
        //UP
        case 50:
        case 19:
            valKey = 19;
            break;
        //DOWN
        case 83:
        case 20:
            valKey = 20;        
            break;
        //LEFT
        case 81:
        case 21:
            valKey = 21;
            break;
        //RIGHT
        case 69:
        case 22:
            valKey = 22;    
            break;
    }

    if (valKey!=0)
    {
        //new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT);
        KeyEvent event1 = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, valKey);

        System.out.println(event1.getKeyCode());    

        return super.onKeyDown(38, event1);
    }
    else
    {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You have to write in javascript document.onkeydown = function(event){ //do something }; For me I couldnt use jquery $(document).on("keydown"). to be able to listen this on javascript thanks this actually works

Comment: crashes when an <input> field has focus.