# How to pass arrow key to Javascript rather than moving WebView itself?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have a WebView with keyboard-controlled javascript in it, but then meet a problem that: Webview won't pass the arrow key to Javascript. Codes are like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mWebView = new MyWebView(this);
    setContentView(mWebView);
}
```

When I launch this `Activity` and press arrow key, the WebView moves and JavaScript in loaded pages does not trigger. Other keys like Enter or alphabets work well.

Is there a way to bypass arrow keys into web pages? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override onKeyDown method for view. You can find how to do that [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172852/android-webview-handle-arrow-keys-in-javacript)