# How to create android TV app using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-tv

I'm trying to create an app for android TVs using Cordova. I was successfully able to build the android app bundle and submitted it to the play store but it got rejected with the following error message:

> Missing DPad functionalityYour app requires user interaction for menus or app navigation. Please make sure that all menus and app navigation are fully functional using a DPad. Please refer to our DPAD Control and Hardware Declarationdocumentation.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus

Comment: Yup, My app can be navigated just by using tabs

Comment: And see: [Handle arrow keys from D-pad on WebView Google Tv app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716840/handle-arrow-keys-from-d-pad-on-webview-google-tv-app). And you've tried: https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=gamepad

Comment: Reminder: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/index.html and https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#cordova-and-android