# Using $(this) inside of a find function jquery

Tags: jquery, find, this

I need to find a div with class 'controller_hover' and then be able to access it with $(this) so I can toggle the next or previous div on a controller dpad left and right.

I have this snippet for the right dpad arrow but its not working:

```
if (event.data.action == "right"){
   $(".controller_hover").find(function(){
       $(this).next('.select').toggleClass("controller_hover");
       $(this).toggleClass("controller_hover");
   })
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="dialog-alert dialog-visible">
  <div class="dialog-border"></div>
  <div class="dialog-title">Select player</div>
  <div class="dialog-message"></div>
  <div class="select controller_hover" data-player="1">Player 1</div>
  <div class="select" data-player="2">Player 2</div>
  <div class="dialog-close">×</div>
  <div class="dialog-clearFloat"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think you *must* use `$(this)`?   `var hover = $(".controller_hover");  hover.next...`   [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) doesn't accept a function callback.

Comment: Yeah thats what I needed to find out.  got it working with a different approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got what I needed with:

```
if (event.data.action == "right"){
    current_player = $(".controller_hover");
    next_player = $(".controller_hover").next(".select");
    
    if(next_player.hasClass('select')){
       current_player.toggleClass("controller_hover");
       next_player.toggleClass("controller_hover");
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the use of `.next(".select")` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562192/how-to-find-next-similar-sibling-moving-down-in-the-dom-tree/38562633#38562633)

Answer (score 0):

Please add your whole code in code snippet tool(<> icon), you can add alert for your logic.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
//if (event.data.action == "right"){
   $(".controller_hover").find(function(){
   alert('hi');
       $(this).next('.select').toggleClass("controller_hover");
       $(this).toggleClass("controller_hover");
   })
//}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dialog-alert dialog-visible">
  <div class="dialog-border"></div>
  <div class="dialog-title">Select player</div>
  <div class="dialog-message"></div>
  <div class="select controller_hover" data-player="1">Player 1</div>
  <div class="select" data-player="2">Player 2</div>
  <div class="dialog-close">×</div>
  <div class="dialog-clearFloat"></div>
</div>
```

Please check this link: [Handle arrow keys from D-pad on WebView Google Tv app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716840/handle-arrow-keys-from-d-pad-on-webview-google-tv-app)

Comment: I'd recommend using `console.log("test")` rather than an `alert`.   An alert will quickly get annoying if it appears more than a few times.   An alert will convert an object to a string, so you often get `[object Object]` (see how many SO questions ask what that is...).

Comment: yes, use console will give you better idea of loop and you know where what values comes