# onKeyDown not fire when pressing Left, Right, Up, Down arrow in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-events

OnKeyDown callback in InputMethodService works for a lot of hardware keyboard buttons but It doesn't fire with Left, Right, Up, Down arrow. How can I handle it?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: you can see the logcat and display the error what your are getting....

Comment: There is no error. I guess Android doesn't support firing event for these kinds of keyboard buttons.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at the [developer documentation on handling key events?](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html) You could try onKeyDown or onKeyUp to only receive one event and print out the keyCode to see what is getting received:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  Log.i("your tag", "Keycode: " + keyCode);
  switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
        leftKeyClick();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
        rightKeyClick();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
        upKeyClick();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
        downKeyClick();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

The [KeyEvent Object reference gives more details.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) If you are still not detecting the arrow keys then you may need to override the onKeyDown or onKeyUp method of your View, [this similar question might be useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172852/android-webview-handle-arrow-keys-in-javacript)